# How to change incoming URL in java Servlet filter and redirect request to the new URL

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I have created a webapp and I am modifying the parameters from the url to decrypt one of the parameters. After decrypting I want to append the parameters to a new URL so that I can get expected response. I have created a HTML which collects input and the landing page is a Java page inbetween I am intercepting the request. I do not want the request to go to the landing page instead I want to send it to a new url.

below is my filter code.

```
    package com.test.secondServlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;

/**
 * Servlet Filter implementation class SecondFilter
 */
@WebFilter("/SecondFilter")
public class SecondFilter implements Filter {
    public String decryptedString;
    private static final String characterEncoding = "UTF-8";
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;
    public String globalKey;
    public String RedirectURL;
    public String DN;
    public String TYPE;
    public String NAME;
    public String NUMBER;
    /**
     * @see Filter#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)
     */

     @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
         //chain.doFilter(req, res);    
         HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            //String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
            //System.out.println(requestURI);
            String url = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURL().toString() +"?"+request.getQueryString();
            System.out.println(url);
            String queryString = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getQueryString();
            DN = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getParameter("DN");
            TYPE = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getParameter("TYPE");
            NAME = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getParameter("NAME");
            NUMBER = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getParameter("encryptedssn");
           // String key = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getParameter("aeskey");   

          //Code to load key from property file
            try {

                String filename = "Secretkey.properties";
                input = SecondFilter.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
                if(input==null){
                        System.out.println("Sorry, unable to find " + filename);
                    return;
                }

                //load a properties file from class path, inside static method
                prop.load(input);
                //get the property value and print it out
                globalKey=prop.getProperty("Secretkey");
                System.out.println("Global Key : "+globalKey);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } 
            //code ends 

            if (queryString!=null) {

                //decryptingssnhere
                    byte[] clearText;
                    try {
                        clearText = AesEncryption.decryptBase64EncodedWithManagedIV(NUMBER, globalKey);
                        decryptedString = new String(clearText,characterEncoding);
                        System.out.println("ClearText:" +decryptedString);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // System.out.println("ClearText:" + new String(clearText,characterEncoding));

            //if(url.startsWith("/SSNdecrypt/SSNdecrypt")){
            System.out.println("queryString :"+queryString);
            System.out.println("DN : "+DN);
            System.out.println("TYPE : "+TYPE);
            System.out.println("NAME : "+NAME);
            System.out.println("S1/ NUMBER : "+NUMBER);
            //System.out.println("key : "+key);
            System.out.println("decrypted S1/ Number : "+decryptedString);
            //String toReplace = url.substring(38);
            System.out.println("input : "+input);
            //String Redirect = "SSNdecrypt?"+queryString.substring(0,13)+decryptedString;
            //System.out.println("redirect : "+Redirect);
            //String newURI = url.replace(queryString, Redirect);
            //System.out.println("new URL"+newURI);
            //String newURI = url.concat("?"+newquerystring);

            RedirectURL = "http://differentservername.com/contentexplorer/servlet/VipDms?";
            String Redirect =RedirectURL+"DN="+DN+"&TYPE="+TYPE+"&NAME="+NAME+"&-NUMBER="+decryptedString;          
            System.out.println("redircting new URL for DOCVIEW : "+Redirect);

            final HttpServletRequestWrapper wrapped = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
                @Override
                public StringBuffer getRequestURL() {
                    final StringBuffer originalUrl = ((HttpServletRequest) getRequest()).getRequestURL();
                    return new StringBuffer(Redirect);
                }
            };
            //chain.doFilter(wrapped, res);
            wrapped.getRequestDispatcher(Redirect).forward(wrapped, res);

            } else {
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            }
            //SSNdecrypt/SSNdecrypt?encryptedssn=1234
            //res.getWriter().println(requestURI.toString());

        /**if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
             String url = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURL().toString();
             String queryString = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getQueryString();
            }**/
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#init(FilterConfig)
     */
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    /**
     * @see Filter#destroy()
     */
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
     }
```

I do not want to use the urlrewriter and would like to do it in the same filter. how do I change the requested URL?

Comment: what is the problem you're facing in your code?

Comment: my request URL is `http://localhost/SSNdecrypt/SSNdecrypt?DN=Docview_Test&TYPE=OL&NAME=OLDNEW_GUL&encryptedssn=FwMzepVbKyMDmEAJPB1gLdVwwWUtwgWmJZTBurg6Bh0%3D` and I would like to change the URL to `http://servername.com/contentexplorer/servlet/VipDms?DN=Docview_Test&TYPE=OL&NAME=GUL&-NUMBER=123456789`. NUMBER here is the encryptedSSN from request URL. I am able to decrypt and all just need to change the url to send request. parameters part is being handled.

Comment: try this  response.sendRedirect("your_url?NUMBER=" + URLEncoder.encode("yourdecryptString", "UTF-8"));

Comment: in my doFilter method, I am unable to use this. it gives error as sendredirect is undefined for servletResponse.

Comment: did you replace 'response' with 'res'?

Comment: yes I did, as I have initialized it that way. I believe class somehow has to extend the servletresponseWrapper. not sure

Comment: I seem to have resolved it using `HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) res;
         resp.sendRedirect(Redirect);`

Comment: did it solve your problem?

Comment: It did partially, as I mentioned to user the sendRedirect, we have to invoke the HTTPServletResponse wrapper class.  But it did give me the answer, I will mark it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) res; resp.sendRedirect(Redirect);` instead of forwarding the request which is `wrapped.getRequestDispatcher(Redirect).forward(wrapped, res);`. Instead of using the request qrapper I am using the HTTP response wrapper and I was able to modify the complete URL from the request url.